# UI testing of Flutter plugin

Tags: android, flutter

I work on some application that performs a complex rendering using a `Mabpox` map.

So I made a Flutter plugin that performs drawing. It works fine inside a `Flutter` app using `PlatformView`.

The Flutter plugin has a lot of native logic. So I would like to test it by some unit and UI tests. Right now I am interested only in Android test, because work on iOS implementation has not been started yet. However I don't understand how I can do testing for the native part of the Plugin.

What is a correct way of doing such ui and unit tests of the Android code of the plugin?

I initially tried to link that module into android test project and setup all the testing there. However it doesn't work, because of `flutter.jar` dependency.

Comment: You can add the `flutter.jar` dependency to your `build.gradle` while you are developing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flutter Driver and `screenshots` (https://github.com/mmcc007/screenshots) to do screenshot UI testing. Its README is quite decent to get you started, even on CI/CD.